# How to install MySQL 8.0?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, database

I will be moving my site from an Ubuntu 18.04 server to an Ubuntu 20.04 server

On my old server I had installed MySQL this way :

```
$ wget -c https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.12-1_all.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.12-1_all.deb
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install mysql-server

ubuntu@www-oldserver-com ~ $ mysql -V
mysql  Ver 8.0.21 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
```

On my new server, MySQL 8 is already in the Ubuntu 20.04 repositories

Should I install MySQL like below or use the other method to not break anything ?

```
$ sudo apt install mysql-server

ubuntu@www-newserver-com:~$ mysql -V
mysql  Ver 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

I seem to have read somewhere that the community MySQL version was not compatible with the versions in the distribution repositories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, simply run the command:

```
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

to install MySQL 8. It is fairly straightforward, works in almost exactly the same way, and has the same packages available. If you’re concerned about manageability, use phpMyAdmin to manage it and control access using .htaccess files.

Here is a great step-by-step on now to install MySQL 8 on Ubuntu 20.04: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: Thanks, so switching from the community version to the ubuntu repository version will not be a problem ?

Comment: Hi @Mathieu, no it won't. Same software, same functionality.